# httpd server simply doesn't want to run anymore

Tags: apache-httpd, cpanel

I have no idea why, if I do `service httpd restart` it just goes back to prompt:

```
root@host [/home3/backup/2013-08-25/accounts]# service httpd start 
httpd (pid 29767) already running
root@host [/home3/backup/2013-08-25/accounts]# service httpd stop
root@host [/home3/backup/2013-08-25/accounts]# service httpd restart
root@host [/home3/backup/2013-08-25/accounts]# service httpd status
```

Nothing! And after a while it reports that apache is not running. No error message whatsoever.

However WHM and CPanel run though.

```
root@host [/home3/backup/2013-08-25/accounts]# service httpd configtest
Syntax OK
root@host [/home3/backup/2013-08-25/accounts]#
```

Notice that it used to work fine.

I got something:
root@host [/home3/backup/2013-08-25/accounts]# service httpd status
Terminated

```
root@host [/home3/backup/2013-08-25/accounts]# 403 Forbidden

   Access is forbidden to the requested page:

     localhost/whm-server-status (port 80)

   Please forward this error screen to localhost's [1]WebMaster.
     __________________________________________________________________


    Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips
    mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
    Server at localhost Port 80

References

   1. mailto:webmaster@buildingsuperteams.com?subject=Error%20message%20[403]%20403%20Forbidden%20for%20localhost/whm-server-status%20port%2080%20on%20Thursday,%2029-Aug-2013%2023:43:54%20MDT
```

forbidden what?

Restarting the whole server works. Restarting apache doesn't/

Comment: you should check the system logs for details. like /var/log/messages, /var/log/(anything that looks like httpd related) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mauro suggests - check the httpd/apache logs - typically under /var/log.  Their locations can vary; to find them, try:

```
find /var/log -name '*http*' -print
find /var/log -name '*apache*' -print
```

You can also check the config - a typical cause of this type of problem:

```
service httpd configtest
```

If a reboot of the server restarts httpd, but the service commands do not, that suggests the problem could be that httpd is started at boot a different way (try `chkconfig` to find out), or some runtime state is leading to the problem (such as a server running low on memory due to too many processes using too much memory).  To check for a possible memory-related cause, try `dmesg` and see if the OOM killer ran.

Comment: done service httpd configtest result is put. What is the location of apache logs?

Comment: I don't see the configtest output; is it in the question?  Found it.

Answer (score 0):

The server was down because I am restoring an account with many domains. The accounts have 270 subdomains. While the restoring is not complete the server is down.

I think this has something to do with cpanel rather than linux.

When the restoring process is complete the server is on.

Checking server logs shows that the server is accepting connections. Somehow it just doesn't show any website.

So the httpd server is on all this time. It just fail to yield any website while another account is in restoring.

That's how the server is down for 3 hours :(